# Align 2 ggplot graphs on two different slides

Tags: r, ggplot2

Dear All,

I want to make 2 choropleths to be put in 2 consecutive slides in a beamer presentation. The boundaries are the same but the fill color is different, so that when I go from the first slide to the second one,the map should not move, but only flip fill colors.

My problem is that I use the SAME incantation of ggplot (except for the fill colour) 2 times  to make the 2 graphs and yet the 2 graphs are not  aligned so that when I transition from the first slide to the second,I can see the second graph shift a little along the horizontal direction.

Due to the confidential nature of the data I am unable to paste my example.

# This example is from :
    # https://medium.com/@anjesh/step-by-step-choropleth-map-in-r-a-case-of-mapping-nepal-7f62a84078d9

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
# clone NepalMaps from https://github.com/anjesh/NepalMaps 

# read shapefile
nepal.adm3.shp <- readOGR(dsn="./NepalMaps-master/baselayers/NPL_adm", layer="NPL_adm3", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# tidy shapefile data to data frame
nepal.adm3.shp.df <- tidy(nepal.adm3.shp, region = "NAME_3")

#write districts to csv file
mydata <- nepal.adm3.shp.df %>%
 distinct(id) %>% 
 write.csv("districts.csv", row.names = FALSE)

mydata <- read.csv("districts.csv")
# Make fake data
mydata$Var1 = as.factor(sample(c(1:5,NA),nrow(mydata),replace= TRUE))
mydata$Var2 = as.factor(sample(c(1:5,NA),nrow(mydata),replace= TRUE))
mydata$Var3 = as.factor(sample(c(1:5,NA),nrow(mydata),replace= TRUE))

myshapeAndData <- left_join(nepal.adm3.shp.df,mydata,by="id")

library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
# Plot using ggplot2.
# EXACT same Graphs,EXCEPT,with different lengths of title / legend title (padded with spaces to make them of equal length)
# The graphs move on transitioning from one slide to the other. I have padded the plot title / legend title with spaces to make them have the same length but it does NOT work.  

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = myshapeAndData, aes(x=long,y=lat,group = group,fill = Var1),color= "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(name ="Var1        ",values = brewer.pal(5,"Greens"),na.value = "pink") +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.4,.8,.3,.2), "in")) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("") +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm")) +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15),axis.text=element_text(size=15),plot.title = element_text(size=20),legend.title =element_text(size=15),axis.title = element_text(size=15)) +
    ggtitle("Title Length 1        ") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 5.6/3.8)

ggsave("graph1.pdf",height =38/4,width = 56/4,units="in")

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = myshapeAndData, aes(x=long,y=lat,group = group,fill = Var2),color = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "My var 2    ",values = brewer.pal(5,"Greens"),na.value = "pink")  +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.4,.8,.3,.2), "in")) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("") +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm")) +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15),axis.text=element_text(size=15),plot.title = element_text(size=20),legend.title =element_text(size=15),axis.title = element_text(size=15)) +
    ggtitle("My title Length 2     ") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 5.6/3.8) 

ggsave("graph2.pdf",height = 38/4,width = 56/4,units="in")

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = myshapeAndData, aes(x=long,y=lat,group = group,fill = Var3),color = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "3rd Variable",values = brewer.pal(5,"Greens") ,na.value = "pink")  +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.4,.8,.3,.2), "in")) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("") +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm")) +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15),axis.text=element_text(size=15),plot.title = element_text(size=20),legend.title =element_text(size=15),axis.title = element_text(size=15)) +
    ggtitle("My title-testing three") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 5.6/3.8)

ggsave("graph3.pdf",height = 38/4,width = 56/4,units="in")

# EXACT same graphs.
# All graphs with the same length of plot title and legend title.
# This works. The graphs do not move on transitioning,they only flip colors.

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = myshapeAndData, aes(x=long,y=lat,group = group,fill = Var1),color= "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(name ="Var1",values = brewer.pal(5,"Greens"),na.value = "pink") +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.4,.8,.3,.2), "in")) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("") +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm")) +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15),axis.text=element_text(size=15),plot.title = element_text(size=20),legend.title =element_text(size=15),axis.title = element_text(size=15)) +
    ggtitle("Title1") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 5.6/3.8)

ggsave("graph1.pdf",height =38/4,width = 56/4,units="in")

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = myshapeAndData, aes(x=long,y=lat,group = group,fill = Var2),color = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Var2",values = brewer.pal(5,"Greens"),na.value = "pink")  +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.4,.8,.3,.2), "in")) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("") +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm")) +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15),axis.text=element_text(size=15),plot.title = element_text(size=20),legend.title =element_text(size=15),axis.title = element_text(size=15)) +
    ggtitle("Title2") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 5.6/3.8) 

ggsave("graph2.pdf",height = 38/4,width = 56/4,units="in")

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = myshapeAndData, aes(x=long,y=lat,group = group,fill = Var3),color = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Var3",values = brewer.pal(5,"Greens") ,na.value = "pink")  +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.4,.8,.3,.2), "in")) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("") +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm")) +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15),axis.text=element_text(size=15),plot.title = element_text(size=20),legend.title =element_text(size=15),axis.title = element_text(size=15)) +
    ggtitle("Title3") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 5.6/3.8)

ggsave("graph3.pdf",height = 38/4,width = 56/4,units="in")
```

## Here is the latex file to display the graphs.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\title[]{Testing maps}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{graph1.pdf}
  \end{tabular} 
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{graph2.pdf}
  \end{tabular} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{graph3.pdf}
  \end{tabular} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: We don't need your actual confidential data. Just some data that represents your problem. Either make some data up, or use a built in dataset, and then make two simple plots that illustrate your problem. There is a bunch of reasons why this may be happening, and without a reproducible example we most likely can't help you.

Comment: The cowplot `align_plots` function can take multiple plots, aligns them, and returns a list of plots that you can then save individually. See last example here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/shared_legends.html

Comment: However, if you’re using the exact same ggplot2 call with just changed fill colors, the plots should be aligned. So something else must have changed between the two plots.

Comment: Hello, I have edited my query and added 2 examples. In example one I generate 3 graphs which use the same incantation of ggplot except for the title and legend title which causes the graphs to not be aligned. I pad the title and legend title with spaces to make them all have the same length but it does not work. In the 2nd example I use the same length title and legend title and the graphs ARE aligned. My query is : How can I plot graphs which have the same incantation of ggplot but different lengths of title / legend title and still be aligned.